# ZFS ZIL Fault on Server

Tags: linux, debian, zfs

I have a server running ZFS with a ZIL log device. We had a failing drive that I had to replace and the tech that was on-site unplugged the ZIL drive.

I cleared the device but I can't seem to figure out how to reconnect it to the array.

It still says faulted and the array is now in a degraded state of course.

Do I have to export and import the pool?

Is there a better way to reconnect the log device?

Comment: Can you `zpool status -v`?

Comment: How about hardware details... OS version, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Solaris Sysadmin guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gfgaa/index.html):

> If a separate log device is not mirrored and the device that contains the log fails, storing log blocks reverts to the storage pool.
>
> Log devices can be added, replaced, attached, detached, imported, and exported as part of the larger storage pool. Log devices can be removed starting in the Solaris 10 9/10 release.

So, do [as you would normally](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1448/gayrd.html#gazgd). Either replace the device with itself

```
# zpool replace tank c0t0d0 c0t0d0
```

or remove and add it again:

```
# zpool remove tank c0t0d0
# zpool add tank log c0t0d0
```